# Failing to install maven on Yosemite

Tags: macos, maven

I'm trying to install maven on osx yosemite, which I did with:

```
sudo port install maven3
```

which returns

```
...
--->  Installing maven3 @3.3.3_0
--->  Activating maven3 @3.3.3_0

To make maven 3.3.3 the default, please run
    sudo port select --set maven maven3

--->  Cleaning maven3
--->  Updating database of binaries
```

but when I run

```
sudo port --set maven3
```

I'm getting:

```
Error: global does not accept --set
```

EDIT

This is my ~/.profile file

```
export PATH=/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:"$PATH"
  2 export PATH=/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:"$PATH"
  3 export PATH=/Users/filipeferminiano/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:$:PATH
```

But mvn is still not recognized in terminal

Comment: I would prefer to download and un zipping it simply instead of installing it at OS

Comment: How could I do this?

Comment: download binary from [here](http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/maven/maven-3/3.3.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.zip), and unzip it somewhere and set it in PATH

Comment: my problem is in setting PATH variable. I already have it, how can I concatenate its current value with  a new one?

Comment: `export PATH=/path/to/your/maven-unzipped/bin:$:PATH` apply it and add it at the last line of your `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: The command should be `sudo port select --set maven maven3`. Are missing `select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with:

sudo port select --set maven maven3